# zend framework updateAction and update the data into database

Tags: zend-framework

I am newly learning Zend framework and currently I am working on this `updateAction` using ID.  I need to update the records and save into Database.

When I am clicking update Action is not working error also silent I don't know how to trace the Error. Error simply return "Application Error" like this.
controller:

```
public function updateAction()
{
    $form = new My_Form_ApplicationForm();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Save');
    $this->view->form = $form;


    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
            $APPID = $form->getValue('APPID');
            $APPNAME = $form->getValue('APPNAME');
            $ID = (int)$form->getValue('ID');

            $apps=My_Application::getInstance();
            $apps->updateApp($ID, $APP_ID, $APP_NAME);

            $this->_helper->redirector('index');

        } else {
            $form->populate($formData);

        }
    } else {
        $ID = $this->_getParam('ID', 0);
        if ($ID > 0) {
            $apps=My_Application::getInstance();
            $form->populate($apps->getApp($ID));

        }
    }
}
```

Next part is model:

```
public function updateApp($ID,$APPID,$APPNAME)
{
    $table = new table1();
    $data = array(
        'APP_ID'=> $APP_ID,
        'APP_NAME'=> $APP_NAME
                 );
    $where = $table->getAdapter()->quoteInto('ID = ?', $ID);
    $table->update($data, $where);      
}
```

Comment: could you please some one help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have an syntax error in your code.

Change `enter code herepublic` to `public`

Next, you have your application set to Production mode, so it will not show exception messages or stack traces. Open your `.htaccess` file and add the line:

`SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development`

If the first part of that already exists, change the value to development.

When you hit refresh now, it should show a full exception message and stack trace. If the `enter code here` bit fixed the problem then the application should just work. If not, can you post the exception and stack trace for further assistance?

Comment: Hi Richard,
(SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development) This line was added in my htaccessfile.php and i fixed all the syntax error too , but still iam getting same Application Error.
could you please help me ?